# Sending multiple id values to controller action; best practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Explanation: I have a grid with a checkbox column where users can check records they want to view details of.  Each checkbox has a value of the ID of that object.  I want to then pass these values to a controller action so that I can render a paged view, as it were.

Now, what I have right now is technically working, but it's ugly and something tells me there's a better way.  Right now I'm creating a JSON string of the array values and passing that, so the route ends up looking like "/Products/Details/["4","5","6"]"

Now, as I said, this works and I can parse out the values in the controller, but something tells me I shouldn't have to.  Am I missing something simple, or does someone know of a decent way of doing this?  The number of values can be arbitrary based on what the user has selected, so I can't create a custom route (I don't think, anyway).

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't read [Phil Haacked - Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) I would highly recommend starting there, it should help alot.

Comment: Huh.  I knew I was missing something simple as I know I've read that blog post before.  Funny thing is, I just talked to my boss, and I may not even need to do this.  But now I know how.  And knowing is half the battle.  Marking as answer, thanks!